# delete font created by CreateFont

Tags: winapi, fonts, bitmap, gdi+, gdi

If I use CreateFont() to create a font  (as non-static variable) and use SelectObject to use itin a function, then before exit that function, I have to select the previous object and use DeleteObject to delete the font.

But if I declare a global variable `HFONT gFont = CreateFont(...)`, then in the `WM_DESTROY` message, should I call `DeleteObject` to delete the font?

Also in this case, if I use `hOldFont = SelectObject(memDC, gFont);` in a function, should I call `SelectObject(memDC, hOldFont);`before exit that function? It seems to me that, for Bitmap, we should do this clean up, but I don't know if this is true for other GDI objects.

Comment: Yes.  Intentionally not restoring a device context when you know that you should is very unwise.  It is undefined behavior with no documented outcome, use at your peril.

Comment: Thanks. And about DeleteObject, do you have any opinion?

Comment: Delete the font when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of each `DeviceContext` (DC) as a canvas. Each of these canvases can only have one active *GDI object* for each **type** at a time. So, you can have one `Brush`, `Pen`, `Font`, etc selected for that canvas as the *active* one.

When you call `SelectObject()` you are setting the active object of that type. Think of it as "picking up the red pen to draw, then picking up the blue pen to draw." If a GDI function takes a `Pen` (such as `Rectangle`), it will use the last selected pen via `SelectObject`. This is why `SelectObject` returns the previous value so you can store it for restoring state when you are done.

You should always use `DestroyObject` on any created GDI object that you no longer need. In addition, you should always use `DeleteDC` for every `CreateDC` call and `ReleaseDC` for every `GetDC` call (when you no longer need the DC).

It is best practice to restore the `DeviceContext` (DC) to the way you found it. So if you set the `Font` or `Brush`, you should restore it to the original value before returning. The only time where restoring is not important is when you are about to dispose of the DC anyways, perhaps in the case of a temporary `Bitmap`.

If you you use `GetStockObject`, you do not need to call `DeleteObject`.

Comment: Thanks. So if I use a global font (which is used all the time the application runs), I still have to delete the font in WM_DESTROY, right?

Comment: Yes, if you use `CreateFont` to create it, you should use `DestroyObject` to free it. However, you do not have to worry about `SelectObject` as your application's DC is going to be destroyed soon after.

Comment: But don't delete an object that's still selected into a DC.  If you've done lots of tweaking to the DC, using `SaveDC` and `RestoreDC` can be a simpler way to manage this.

Comment: Good point @AdrianMcCarthy, if you have several DCs using shared objects, only call `DeleteObject` when no other DC will be using it (it has been quite a while since I've worked with GDI).

Comment: @SiLo: For some GDI objects, (e.g., bitmaps) you should never have them selected into two different DCs at the same time.  (You're probably safe with stock objects.)  And it's important to select those out of a DC before you delete the DC.

Comment: Windows tracks the resources your application is using, and will automatically free them when the application exits. In other words, while it may give you a good feeling of esthetic completeness to delete your globally used font on exit, there is no penalty on not doing so.

Answer (score 1):

A Delphi (Pascal) example:

```
Procedure AngleTextOut(hDC: THandle; const sTxt: string; iX, iY, iH, iAngle: integer);
var
    aryC: array[0..255] of Char;
    hFont, hFontOld: THandle;
begin
    StrPCopy(aryC, sTxt);
    hFont:= CreateFont(-iH, 0, iAngle *10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'arial');
    hFontOld:= SelectObject(hDC, hFont);
    TextOut(hDC, iX, iY, aryC, StrLen(aryC));
    SelectObject(hDC, hFontOld);
    DeleteObject(hFont);
end;//  AngleTextOut
```